# What register is used instead of FP (Frame Pointer) in 8086 assembly?

Tags: x86-16, stack-pointer

What register is used in 8086 assembly instead of FP?
I think it is SP or ESP. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is `FP` from?  What is it mnemonic for?

If it's a mnemonic for "Frame Pointer" than *`BP` is more likely the register equivalent in the x86 family.  If it's for the push-down stack then *`SP` is the equivalent in the x86 family.

Comment: I meant "Frame Pointer". Thank you.